# Unexpected Behavior of menu command link to function

Tags: python, function, menu, tkinter

Following is a Python script to display a menu(file,option) where option is used to initiate a function conf.
As I had assumed, the conf fun will only execute when i press the respective menu widget.
That means 'haha' will only be printed when i press option/Edit comp list and similarly 'nana' will only be printed when i press option/Edit pvt list

**However, as i start the script top.py, the 'haha' and 'nana' are printed with the start. That is because the conf function is executed two times at the start. This is unexpected. Please advice.**

The error appears to be in following statements:

> **menu_option.add_command(label="Edit Comp List",command=conf('comp'))
>   menu_option.add_command(label="Edit pvt List",command=conf('pvt'))**

Code:-

```
#File name :top.py
from Tkinter import *
import ttk

def conf(section):
    if section == 'comp':
        print 'haha'
    if section == 'pvt':
        print 'nana'
    pass

root = Tk()
root.title("NRUNTEST GUI VERSION 1")

menuframe = Frame(root)
menuframe.grid(column=0,row=0)
menuframe.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
menuframe.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)

buttonh = ttk.Button(root, text='Quit',command=root.quit)
buttonh.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=(E,W))

menubar = Menu(menuframe)
menu_file = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
menu_option = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
menubar.add_cascade(menu=menu_file, label='File')
menubar.add_cascade(menu=menu_option, label='Option')
**menu_option.add_command(label="Edit Comp List",command=conf('comp'))**
menu_option.add_separator()
**menu_option.add_command(label="Edit pvt List",command=conf('pvt'))**
menu_file.add_separator()

root.config(menu=menubar)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is quite simple:

```
menu_option.add_command(label="Edit Comp List",command=conf('comp'))
```

When you pass this argument:

```
command=conf('comp')
```

You aren't actually passing it. You are passing the *result* of `conf('comp')` as your function. The result of that function is a `print` statement, which is what you observe.

Try making separate functions for each case and add the command like this:

```
command=function_name
```

Comment: hey @Blender : I did try with separate functions.It worked.
But my actual function is quite huge, which is by large doing a generic operation based on passed 'section' variable.

is there anyway I can use a singular function and pass a string?

Comment: Sure, use a lambda. Instead of passing command=conf("comp") as the argument, pass command=lambda: conf("comp").